# Passing 2D array of char as argument

Tags: c, arrays, function, allocation

I made a function that loads lines and save it to array which dinamically alocates everytime the getline function load a new line but It gives me segmentation fault when i want to print all saved lines from array in the end of my code. Could you please tell me where the problem is ? When i remove the function and put everything to main it works fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void load(char **array,int *index) {

        int riadok;
        size_t len = 0;
        char *buffer = NULL;

        printf("Slova:\n");
        while( ( riadok = getline(&buffer,&len,stdin) ) != -1 ) {

            if (riadok == 1){
                break;  
            }

            array = (char**) realloc ( array, ( *index + 1 ) * sizeof( char* ) );
            array[*index] = (char*) malloc ( (riadok + 1) * sizeof(char*) );
            strcpy( array[*index], buffer );

            *index = *index + 1;

      }

    }

int main()
{

   int index = 0;
   int i;
   char **array = NULL;

   load(array,&index);

   for (i = 0; i < index; i++ )
     printf("%s",array[i]);


   return 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C arguments are pass by value. When you pass `array` in `main` to the function then it just copied to the parameter `array` in function `load`. The statement

```
array = (char**) realloc ( array, ( *index + 1 ) * sizeof( char* ) );
```

modify the pointer `array` to new allocated memory.

Pass the address of `array` from `main` with some changes to `load` function

```
void load(char ***array, int *index) { // Use pointer to pointer to pointer

    int riadok;
    size_t len = 0;
    char *buffer = NULL;

    printf("Slova:\n");
    while( ( riadok = getline(&buffer,&len,stdin) ) != -1 ) {
        //printf("%d\n", riadok);
        //printf("%s\n", buffer);
        if (riadok == 1){
            break;
        }


        *array = realloc ( *array, ( *index + 1 ) * sizeof( char* ) );
        if(*array == NULL)
            break;

        array[0][*index] = malloc(riadok + 1);
        if(array[0][*index])
            strcpy( array[0][*index], buffer );
        //else
        //  printf("Memory Not allocated\n");


        *index = *index + 1;
    }
    free(buffer);
}
```

and call it from `main` as

```
load(&array,&index);
```

Comment: So in my code i coppied array to function thats why it worked in my function and outside function it did not work and gave me segmentation fault because i wanted to print array that pointed nowhere? Dont know if i understand correctly. With the edited code compilator gives me  3 errors.

Comment: Almost. `array` in `main` is pointing to `NULL` and it is not modified by function `load`. Dereferencing it will invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: Getting 3 errors : slova.c:18:68: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘char**’ [-fpermissive]
         *array = realloc ( array, ( *index + 1 ) * sizeof( char* ) );
                                                                    ^
slova.c:19:63: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘char**’ [-fpermissive]
         array[*index] = malloc ( (riadok + 1) * sizeof(char*) );
                                                               ^
slova.c:20:39: error: cannot convert ‘char**’ to ‘char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘char* strcpy(char*, const char*)’
   strcpy( array[*index], buffer );

Comment: Can't say anything without looking at the complete code.

Comment: @Michi; There is a `main` function in the question. Some serious issues with this code. I am working on it to fix.

Comment: It wouldn't be better if load() could return a char ** after allocating memory instead of passing a char*** ?

Comment: @kvway; How did you call the function?

Comment: You are not allocating memory for `buffer` before `getline()`

Comment: @Bob__; No need to allocate. `len` is zero. `getline` will allocate it by itself. Read [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html): *If `*lineptr` is set to `NULL` and `*n` is set `0` before the call, then
       `getline()` will allocate a buffer for storing the line.*

Comment: @Bob__; No. You need to free it explicitly. Added to the answer.

Comment: I'm calling function like u wrote , with load(&array,&index);

Comment: @kvway; I compiled it with xcode on my mac and it is running fine just giving a warning about `getline` (as it is not a standard library function).

Comment: I use g++ compiler and it gives me 2 errors slova.c: In function ‘void load(char***, int*)’:
slova.c:21:69: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘char**’ [-fpermissive]
         *array = realloc ( *array, ( *index + 1 ) * sizeof( char* ) );
                                                                     ^
slova.c:25:45: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
         array[0][*index] = malloc(riadok + 1); , will try gcc

Comment: @kvway; Check the extension of your program file. It must be `.cpp`. Change it to `.c` and use GCC instead of g++. g++ is a C++ compiler. In C++ you need to cast the return value of `malloc` family function.